# Как дополнить логику замены символа табуляции на любой другой символ

Tags: linux, c

возникла проблема с тем что я пытаюсь заменить символ табуляции, в котором `2` символа пробела - на другой символ, но при замене я получаю один символ вместо двух и я понимаю что проблема в логике программы, как её можно дополнить?
Трудность идеи ещё в том что я читаю файл, а затем перезаписываю его новым содержимым и возникает путаница с позициями функции `fseek`

Вот небольшой пример:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TABN 2
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int c;
    FILE *stream;

    /* в аргументе к программе передается путь файла */
    if (argc > 1) {
        /* открыть файл для чтения и его преобразования */
        if ((stream = fopen(argv[1], "r+")) != NULL) {
            while ((c = fgetc(stream)) != EOF) {
                if (c == '\t') {
                    fseek(stream, -1, SEEK_CUR);
                    fputc('#', stream);
                }
            }

            fclose(stream);
        } else
            perror("Error");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

В моем файле лежит строка (первый отступ это табуляция из 2 символов пробела):

```
   abc
```

И после выполнения программы я получаю

```
#abc
```

А хотелось бы увидеть

```
##abc
```

Как этого добиться?
И да я знаю что в табуляции обычно 8 символов пробела, пример для более простого понимания

Comment: Потому что в табуляции не может быть никаких пробелов. Табуляция не пробел.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то табуляция не есть какое-то конкретное количество символов. Табуляция в N символов, каковое N может быть разным у разных вьюверов/редакторов, означает, что следующий символ будет в ближайшей позиции, превышающей текущую и кратную N.

Так что в общем случае вам нужно читать строками, в каждой строке разбираться, сколько пробелов добавить - например, при табуляции 4 символа строка

```
\tab\tcd
```

превращается в

```
####ab##cd
```

т.е. символы табуляции заменяются на разное количество других символов.

Простая замена в файле теперь не сработает, так что лучше писать в другой файл, которым затем заменить исходный...

Comment: спасибо за рекомендации

Comment: Табуляция -- это дополнение до 8. А как её **отображают** разные программы -- это другое.

Comment: @0andriy Не более чем традиция, пошедшая от пишущих машинок. Как в той байке, что диаметр ускорителя шаттла определяется шириной лошадиного крупа в древнем Риме.

Comment: Ну разве это не очевидно? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key

Comment: *Despite five characters being the typical paragraph indentation on typewriters at that time, the horizontal tab size of 8 evolved because as a power of two it was easier to calculate...*

Comment: @0andriy Спасибо за подтверждение моих слов, что 8 символов - "ну вот так принято у некоторых" и не более того :)

Comment: Huh? Вы читали про пишущие машинки? Там пять.